# Conditional expectation calculation: $E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb{I}_{X_i \le 2}}{n}| \sum_{i=1}^n X_i]$

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

I am trying to calculate the UMVUE for $Pr[X_1\le 2]$ where

$X_1,...X_n \sim_{iid} Exp(\theta) $.

I know that the average number of incidents where the random variable is less than or equal to $2$ is an unbiased estimator of $Pr[X_1\le2]$.  Thus,

$$E \left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\Bbb{I}_{X_i \le 2}}{n} \right] = Pr[X_1\le2]$$

The problem that I have is here.

Utilizing Lehmann-Scheffe's Theorem I want to evaluate

$$E \left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\Bbb{I}_{X_i \le 2}}{n} | \sum_{i=1}^nX_i \right] $$

but I am not sure how to procede from here.

Letting $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ I know that $Y \sim \Gamma(n,\theta)$ so I know its distribution and I have

$$nE \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb X_i\le 2 | Y \right]$$

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172215/find-the-joint-distribution-of-x-1-and-sum-i-1n-x-i?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I was wondering why you would know such an old reference.  You answered this question in the past.  It was very useful, thank you.

Comment: You could post an answer to this question to remove it from the unanswered queue.